# Pausing a cloth simulation

Tags: animation, physics, cloth-simulation

I am making an animation where a default cube is launched from a tube and explodes.  I have a particle system and an Explode modifier and a cloth system to simulate an explosion with cloth like ruins. The problem is that the simulation started at frame 1, I need to start at frame 60 at 60fps to allow one second for the object to be launched in the air.  I have no idea how to solve this.
Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

In Cloth settings open the **Cache** panel, and find **Simulation start** property.

[image]